# How can I get the probability estimate of a text classification prediction with LibShortText using the logistic regression classifier?

Tags: python, nlp, probability, text-classification, libshorttext

[LibShortText](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libshorttext/) is an open source library for short-text classification  that relies on [liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/).

I read on https://github.com/cjlin1/liblinear:

> -b probability_estimates: whether to output probability estimates, 0 or 1 (default 0); currently for logistic regression only

How can I get the probability estimate of a prediction with LibShortText using the logistic regression classifier?

Comment: When you call `predict_text()`, you should get back a `PredictionResult` which has a `decvals` member. Are you looking for something other than what's in `decvals`?